# C# Replacing values from one dictionary to another

Tags: c#, object, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries with the same keys but different values. I need to find in dictionary1 all values that are equal to 1 and replace them with the value in dictionary2. I could edit the first dictionary or better idea is to save the new values into another dictionary either way is fine. My idea was to use a foreach loop and then find any values in dictionary1 == 1 then go inside dictionary2 and extract that value for that key and save it into dictionary1 or another dictionary for that key.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Practice_With_Dictionaries
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


                object[] keys= new object[5];
                keys[0] = "1111";
                keys[1] = "2222";
                kesy[2] = "3333";
                kesy[3] = "4444";
                kesy[4] = "5555";


                object[] speed = new object[5];
                speed[0] = 1;
                speed[1] = 2;
                speed[2] = 1;
                speed[3] = 1;
                speed[4] = 5;

                object[] speed2 = new object[5];
                speed2[0] = 1;
                speed2[1] = 2;
                speed2[2] = 3;
                speed2[3] = 4;
                speed2[4] = 5;





   Dictionary<object, object> dictionary1 = new Dictionary<object,object>();
   Dictionary<object, object> dictionar2 = new Dictionary<object, object>();

                for (int iRow = 0; iRow < interfaceKeys.Length; iRow++)
                {

                  dictionary1.Add(keys[iRow], (double)speed[iRow]);
                  dictionary2.Add(keys[iRow], (double)speed2[iRow]);


                }


                // for each loop with if statements




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But you don't have two dictionaries. You want to build dictionaries?

Comment: Your code example does not match your question.  Can you create dictionaries in your code example so we can see what data you are starting with?  You can also use initializer syntax for collections (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx)

Comment: I declared two dictionaries  Dictionary<object, object> dictionary1 = new Dictionary<object,object>();
   Dictionary<object, object> dictionar2 = new Dictionary<object, object>(); in the code above. They have the same keys but different values. From the answers i'm seeing using linq is the best way to achieve what i want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have `string` as key, and `int` as value, then you should use `Dictionary<string, int>` instead of `Dictionary<object, object>`.

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary2 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
// fill your dictionaries
```

Now if you always have matching keys between two dictionaries:

```
var keys = dictionary1.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == 1).Select(kvp => kvp.Key);
foreach (var key in keys)
    dictionary1[key] = dictionary2[key];
```

Otherwise

```
var keys = dictionary1.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == 1).Select(kvp => kvp.Key);
foreach (var key in keys)
{
    int value;
    if (dictionary2.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        dictionary1[key] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ and the [ToDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) method (I made some changes to simplify your code, I hope this is acceptable):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var keys = new string[5] { "1111", "2222", "3333", "4444", "5555" };

    var speed = new double[5] { 1, 2, 1, 1, 5 };

    var speed2 = new double[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    var dictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, double>();
    var dictionary2 = new Dictionary<string, double>();

    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < keys.Length; iRow++)
    {
        dictionary1.Add(keys[iRow], speed[iRow]);
        dictionary2.Add(keys[iRow], speed2[iRow]);
    }

    // the solution
    var result = dictionary1.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, kv => kv.Value == 1 ? dictionary2[kv.Key] : kv.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
var dictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"a", "1"},
    {"b", "2"},
    {"c", "3"},
    {"d", "3"}
};



var dictionary2 = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"a", "1"},
    {"b", "22"},
    {"c", "33"}
};

var result = dictionary1
    .Where(d => dictionary2.ContainsKey(d.Key) && dictionary2[d.Key] == d.Value);
```

result will contain all values that have same keys in dictinary1 and dictinary2 with values in dictinary1.